# Setting ID for Radio buttons in Django

Tags: django

It is great that Django 1.4 allows fine graining of [radio select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect)

```
{% for radio in form.important_client reversed%}
      {{radio.tag}}<label for="????">{{radio.choice_label}}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

but for some odd reason when using this methodology, the `<input>` have no IDs.  And hence I can't set the `<label for='ID' />` accordingly. That causes big issues in my CSS.

Is there anyway to get the IDs set nonetheless?

Comment: I am not familiar with topic, but did you try `{{ radio }}` and `{{ radio.label_tag }}`?

Comment: Yes `{{radio}}` works fine, however it puts the `<input>` right into a '<label>'  therefore you don't have the fine graining any longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While debuging a RadioSelect rendering, I got no idea of using radio tag and label elegantly. So here is my attempt to solve your problem:

```
{% for radio in form.important_client reversed %}
    <input name="{{ radio.name }}" type="radio" id="radio_{{ radio.index }}" value={{ radio.choice_value }}>
    <label for="radio_{{ radio.index }}">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of `radio.index` property, which is not documented, you can use `forloop.counter`.

Just in case I attach a screenshot of debug window, where example of `radio` context is shown (`form_of_field` variable on a figure):
[image: radio select debug]

Comment: +1 thanks. That looks promising. Indeed didn't know about radio.index.

Comment: note for people who is still searching for how to render value in django 2.1 and above. use radio.data.value in template

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do that, it might not be the best but it works. In your form you can set the id for each of the choices like this:

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (('1','Available'),('2','Not Available'))
    input   = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(attrs={'id' : 'myId'},choices=CHOICES)
```

Then on your template:

```
{% for radio in form.input %}
    {{ radio }}
{% endfor %}
```

And your HTML will look like this:

```
<label for="myId_0"><input id="myId_0" name="input" type="radio" value="1"></label> Available
<label for="myId_0"><input id="myId_0" name="input" type="radio" value="2"></label> Not Available
```

I hope this works!