# Django - Set different id for each radio button choice

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-widget

I want to set different id for each radio choice.

My Model:-

```
class Preference(models.Model):
      BOARD_CHOICES = [('CB', 'CBSE'), ('IC', 'ICSE'), ('SB', 'State Board'),
                 ('IB', 'International Board')]
      Board = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=BOARD_CHOICES, default='CBSE', blank=False)
```

My Form:-

```
class PreferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Preference
       fields = ['Board']
       widgets = {
           'Board': forms.RadioSelect(),
           }
```

i.e for the radio button with label 'CBSE' I want to set id to say 'choice_1' and so on.

All help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768801/setting-id-for-radio-buttons-in-django)
?

I wrapped-up with something like this:

```
<label>{{ form.origem.label }}</label>
{% for choice in form.origem %}
    <div class="">
        {{ choice.tag }}
        <label class="radio-style-1-label" for="id_{{form.origem.name}}_{{forloop.counter0}}">{{ choice.choice_label }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```