# Listing form items (radio buttons)

Tags: django, django-forms

I've set up a form that is basically a listing of addresses as radio buttons. This form allows the user to select the address, which they previously entered, to use as the ailling address. Within the template, rather than outputting the form like this:

```
 <form method="POST" action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
 </form>
```

I'd like to output the form like this so that I can capture the id of the address and allow the user to click a link that will allow them to edit the address instance (the following outlines what I want to do, but the code won't work):

```
 {% for form in forms %}
    {{ form.address }}<a href="{% url 'address_edit' id=form.id %}">Edit</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure if this will help, but here is my model and form.

Forms.py

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    billing_address = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=UserAddress.objects.all(),
    widget = forms.RadioSelect,
    empty_label = None,
    )
```

Models.py

```
class UserAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCheckout, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=STATE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

If needed, I can provide the view, but I'm not sure that that will help at this point. Thanks a ton!

Edit: HTML output of the form is as follows:

```
        <form class="addressselect" method="POST" action=''>

        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='TARLwNZUb0SL06Btika0xKR2AXIDrEnEbKDLiDnpNdcGL8SvwDMxjZkODJAZrrnO' />



          <tr><th><label for="id_billing_address_0">Billing address:</label></th><td><ul id="id_billing_address">
    <li><label for="id_billing_address_0"><input type="radio" name="billing_address" value="18" required id="id_billing_address_0" />
 434 Pine Street, Vancouver, BC</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_billing_address_1"><input type="radio" name="billing_address" value="15" required id="id_billing_address_1" />
 123 fake street, Calgary, AB...</label>

</li>


</ul></td></tr>
```

Comment: From your view, you need to pass the list of addresses (UserAddress) for the user.   This does not need to be a form. It's a simple list/table view - Id, user, address as columns. One each column you can have the edit link which allows them to edit the address instance

Comment: can you add the output of your `{{ form }}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting ID for Radio buttons in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768801/setting-id-for-radio-buttons-in-django)

Comment: @Nihal Sharma That's a good point, but this form also allows them to "select" the address that they want to use. So the functionality on this page is 2 fold. They can click the radio button associated with the correct address then click "next", which takes them to the checkout page OR they can click "change" beside the address to modify the values within that address (i.e. City, State, etc.)

Comment: @seuling Added the output in my original post. Thanks!

Comment: @Selcuk I'm not trying to set the IDs of radio buttons. I'm trying to obtain the ID of the model instance represented by each radio button.

Comment: So I've realized that the 'value' variable in the HTML output is the one that contains the ID of the object. How can I output this using template tags?

Answer (score 0):

{{radio.data.value}} will get you the ID of the model instance represented by the radio button where radio is your index variable.